# Property 'parseFloat' does not exist on type 'NumberConstructor' angular2

Tags: parsing, angular, typescript2.0

Property 'parseFloat' does not exist on type 'NumberConstructor'

assigned parseFloat  code below

```
DistributionAmount: Number.parseFloat(this.glAccountObject.glAccountAmount),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DistributionAmount: Number = parseFloat(this.glAccountObject.glAccountAmount),
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this in the file which is throwing error.

```
interface INumber {
    parseFloat: Function
}
declare var Number: INumber;
```